# MongoDB replicaset external access - keep getting internal cluster names

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I must be doing something terribly wrong. I have a replicaset configured using the MongoDB community operator, deployed in GKE, and exposed via LoadBalancers.

This replicaset has 3 members. I have defined the replicaSetHorizons like so:

```
  replicaSetHorizons:
  - mongo-replica: document-0.mydomain.com:30000
  - mongo-replica: document-1.mydomain.com:30001
  - mongo-replica: document-2.mydomain.com:30002
```

I then use mongosh from an external source (local computer outside of GKE) to connect:

```
mongosh "mongodb://<credentials>@document-0.mydomain.com:30000,document-1.mydomain.com:30001,document-2.mydomain.com:30002/admin?ssl=false&replicaSet=document"
```

I do not use SSL for now because I am testing this deployment. What I found is mongosh always returns this error:

```
MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND document-0.document-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local
```

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong? Why is my internal clustername being given to mongosh to attempt the connection?

If I try to connect to a single member of the replicaset, the connection will succeed. If I run `rs.conf()`, I see the following (which looks correct??):

```
{
  _id: 'document',
  version: 1,
  term: 1,
  members: [
    {
      _id: 0,
      host: 'document-0.document-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017',
      arbiterOnly: false,
      buildIndexes: true,
      hidden: false,
      priority: 1,
      tags: {},
      horizons: { 'mongo-replica': 'document-0.mydomain.com:30000' },
      secondaryDelaySecs: Long("0"),
      votes: 1
    },
    {
      _id: 1,
      host: 'document-1.document-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017',
      arbiterOnly: false,
      buildIndexes: true,
      hidden: false,
      priority: 1,
      tags: {},
      horizons: { 'mongo-replica': 'document-1.mydomain.com:30001' },
      secondaryDelaySecs: Long("0"),
      votes: 1
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      host: 'document-2.document-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017',
      arbiterOnly: false,
      buildIndexes: true,
      hidden: false,
      priority: 1,
      tags: {},
      horizons: { 'mongo-replica': 'document-2.mydomain.com:30002' },
      secondaryDelaySecs: Long("0"),
      votes: 1
    }
  ],
  protocolVersion: Long("1"),
  writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault: true,
  settings: {
    chainingAllowed: true,
    heartbeatIntervalMillis: 2000,
    heartbeatTimeoutSecs: 10,
    electionTimeoutMillis: 10000,
    catchUpTimeoutMillis: -1,
    catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis: 30000,
    getLastErrorModes: {},
    getLastErrorDefaults: { w: 1, wtimeout: 0 },
    replicaSetId: ObjectId("62209784e8aacd8385db1609")
  }
}
```

Comment: Command `rs.info()` does not exist in MongoDB

Comment: My apologies. I have edited the question. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReplicaSetHorizons feature does not work **without** using SSL/TLS certificates.
Quoting from Kubernetes Operator [reference](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kubernetes-operator/master/reference/k8s-operator-specification/#spec.connectivity.replicaSetHorizons):

> This method to use split horizons requires the Server Name Indication extension of the TLS protocol

In order to make this work, you need to include

- TLS certificate
- TLS key
- CA key

TLS Certificate must contain DNS names of all your replica sets in Subject Alternative Name (SAN) section

There is a [tutorial](https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-kubernetes-operator/blob/master/docs/external_access.md) at operator github pages. You need to complete all steps, **certificate issuance cannot be skipped**.

Certificate resource (using cert-manager.io CRD)

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: cert-manager-certificate
spec:
  secretName: mongodb-tls
  issuerRef:
    name: ca-issuer
    kind: Issuer
  duration: 87600h
  commonName: "*.document-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local"
  dnsNames:
    - "*.document-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local"
    - "document-0.mydomain.com"
    - "document-1.mydomain.com"
    - "document-2.mydomain.com"
```

MongoDBCommunity resource excerpt

```
spec:
  type: ReplicaSet
  ...
  replicaSetHorizons:
    - mongo-replica: document-0.mydomain.com:30000
    - mongo-replica: document-0.mydomain.com:30001
    - mongo-replica: document-0.mydomain.com:30002
  security:
    tls:
      enabled: true
      certificateKeySecretRef:
        name: mongodb-tls
      caConfigMapRef:
        name: ca-config-map
```

Secret **mongodb-tls** will by of type **tls** and contain *ca.crt, tls.crt* and *tls.key* fields representing Certificate Authority certificate, TLS certificate and TLS key respectively.
ConfigMap **ca-config-map** will contain ca.crt field only

More info at: [mongodb-operator-secure-tls](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kubernetes-operator/master/tutorial/secure-tls/#configure-tls-for-a-replica-set)

Comment: I take it only an internal CA can be used to generate this type of cert? I can't use a public CA because no public CA will verify private DNS namespaces. This means a Kubernetes deployment of MongoDB can never use a public cert? And a public cert protected MongoDB instance can only work with say, EC2 instances?

Comment: I assume you are right about public CA not providing certificate for internal DNS namespaces (never tried it though). Therefore it is impossible to use public cert. Deployment on EC2 is not deployment on Kubernetes, but yes, you can make it work with public certs there. 
I ended up deploying both database and its clients in single cluster.